# Angular 7 Modal don't show

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I have an issue with Bootstrap Modal. I do everything requested but do not show when i click the button :

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalusername">
<i class="fas fa-pen text-white"></i></a>
```

I tried button version too

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalusername">
<i class="fas fa-pen text-white"></i></button>
```

And here is the modal section

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalusername" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class=" modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalusername">{{user.username | translate }}</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>TEST</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When i click the button, he's still pushed, so the toggle effect works but don't show.

Somebody have an answer ?

Thank you all ^^

Comment: You seem to have 2 different fields with the id "modalusername". It's possible that it could be related to that. I'm not sure, but instead of id="modalusername" on the div with class "modal fade", you can try to put #modalusername and see if there are any differences.

Comment: It would be better if you post a stackblitz because we can see the versions of the dependencies you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive and @hostLister to add and remove the class that activates the pop up...
I don't know how other frontend guys will see it but I build my modals with CSS and a check box, practically and thing that I need to toggle and it works super fine no need for directives and work around... I hope you got some insight from my answer #cheers